# dbo insert in php error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this error when I tried to submit my newly created form.
The db_connect(); is just a new PDO.

```
$db = db_connect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$ww = $_POST['ww'];
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$tussenvoegsel = $_POST['tussenvoegsel'];
$rights = $_POST['rights'];

try{


$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gebruiker(email, wachtwoord, rol_id,groep_id, voornaam, achternaam, tussenvoegsel)
    VALUES(:mail, :ww, :rolid, :groepid,:voornaam,:achternaam,:achternaam,:tussenvoegsel)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "mail" => "$mail",
    "ww" => "$ww",
    "rolid" => "$rights",
    "groepid" => "1",
    "voornaam" => "$naam",
    "achternaam"=>"$achternaam",
    "tussenvoegsel" =>"$tussenvoegsel"));
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }}
```

this is the error

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: you are specifing 7 columns in your insert and giving 8 inside values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327233/insert-value-list-does-not-match-column-list-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-va)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have `achternaam` twice in the parameterlist

> ... ,:voornaam,:achternaam,:achternaam, ....